# How to apply a Grafana time series value to all panels on a dashboard

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have some panels with time series data like, user searches.
I wanted to normalize the data by the amount of users created during the same time.

I can do it on a panel by panel basis by Adding a new Query for UsersCreated and apply a transformation with a binary operation to the original query.

However, I'd like to apply this transformation to all panels at the dashboard level, but I can't seem to find the right thing to do. I can create a UserCreated variable - but it always seems to come out as a quick series of integer values - and I'm not sure how to apply the transform based on this data.

I have it set as a Variable of Type Query., but I just get a big set of "Preview of values"

Comment: What is your data source and query? You probably need to adjust your query to receive only last value. Plus it's unclear what are queries on your panels.